# How to read query string value from ahref click event by jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to read the query string value from this anchor tag by jquery.

```
<td><a href="#?acckey={{user.key()}}" class="generate_url">Get URL</a></td>
```

this is what i wrote and it is not working

```
$('.generate_url').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        alert(acckey)

    });

});
```

but this is not working. any one know to fix this issue?

Comment: by _querystring value_ do you mean `acckey={{user.key()}}` or `{{user.key()}}` or `user.key()`?

Comment: is a Jinja Binding  for  HTML setting the user id value

Comment: ok, but my what the answer to my question? :)

Comment: Can you show the rendered HTML instead of the template code?

Comment: @EvlikoshDawark good, so my answer fits your need

Comment: @Jack well I cannot show the HTML because it is to illegal and in here i did not show the replica what i did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.generate_url').on('click', function() {
    var m = this.href.match(/acckey=(.*)/),
    acckey = m ? m[1] : '';

    alert(acckey);
});
```

It matches the `href` value against a regular expression and uses the first memory group. The `acckey` will be set to empty string if no match was found.

**Update**

To get the whole match (i.e. "acckey=xxx"), you would need to use `m[0]` instead of `m[1]`.

Btw, I've removed the `.each()` because you were only adding a click handler.

Comment: I think the brackets `{{user.key()}}` came from template syntax (e.g. Jinja). Hence in the rendered markup there won't be any brackets.

Comment: @EvlikoshDawark what results do you get then?

Comment: @EvlikoshDawark I've updated my answer; just use `m[0]` to get the full match

Comment: anyway $('.generate_url').on('click', function() undefined error anyway what you have done is correct @Jack. Thank you .

Answer (score 2):

Based on the parsing function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1249581), we can make the universal solution:

```
function getParameterByName(query_string, name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(query_string);
    if (results == null) return "";
    else return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

$(".generate_url").click(function() {
    var query_string = this.href.substring(this.href.indexOf("?"));
    var acckey = getParameterByName(query_string, "acckey");
    alert(acckey);
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/dQ8Z9/

---

To get query string you can simply use this:

```
$(".generate_url").click(function() {
    var query_string = this.href.substring(this.href.indexOf("?") + 1);
    alert(query_string);
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/dQ8Z9/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.generate_url').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        alert($(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*?\?/, ""));  
        /* return: acckey={{user.key()}} */
    });
});
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f4vN7/